# Symfony 2 CronJob

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, cron

Hello i have a function in a controller :

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect"))
die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");

if (!($con = ssh2_connect("myipadresherenotshowingtoyouguys", 22))) {
echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
// try to authenticate with username root, password secretpassword
if (!ssh2_auth_password($con, "blablabla", "blablabla!")) {
    echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
} else {
    // allright, we're in!
    echo "okay: logged in...\n";

    // execute a command
    $command = 'ssid "Wentzo test2" hide-ssid';
    if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, $command))) {
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {

        $stream2 = ssh2_exec($con, $command_save);
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream, 4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }

        fclose($stream);
    }
}
}
```

I want to run this script as a cronjob when a submit button is pressed.
But i have no idea how to do this in symfony 2.

Someone got a solution ? 
Example maybe ?

Comment: What do you mean by cronjob? Do you want to run an asynchronous script or do you want to run the script at specific times continuously?

Comment: Assuming that you want to run this script asynchronously, you should have a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The Process component looks interesting! Can i set a timer for each command that is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is Queuing.

I would suggest you use something like Beanstalkd, RabbitMQ, or any other queuing system to handle this.

The idea will be that you put your handling method into a Symfony command:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#creating-a-basic-command

In that command, you're going to read from the queue, and run the process based on the "Job" in the queue.

In you controller, the only thing you will do is push a new Job into that queue. The job will contain some data which you can use in your command to process.

To understand the concept a bit more, you can go through these slides: http://www.slideshare.net/cakper/2014-0821-symfony-uk-meetup-scaling-symfony2-apps-with-rabbit-mq

And you might want to read up some more on the concept of queuing.

For some reason I'm not able to find a good tutorial on Symfony2 and queuing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nico. Will look into that, it turns out that a cronjob is not the right thing to work with this.